How can an RS-422 transceiver not have a negative voltage rail?
I'm looking at using an RS-422 transceiver for a project. I've chosen TI's THVD1551.
I'd like to connect UART TX/RX from a microcontroller to the single-ended input/outputs R (pin 2) and D (pin 3):

Outputs A and B and inputs Z and Y are the differential RS-422 signals, which will be traveling to another device over a long distance.
TI specifies that there are Vcc and GND power ports - no negative voltage supply:

However, as I understand differential signaling, the complementary signals are inverted - one is, say, +5V, and the other is -5V. The datasheet specifies the following truth table for high/low outputs:

And the positive/negative threshold voltages are given by the following values:

How is it that the device can compare the differential signal to negative thresholds? If I'm only supplying the device from +5V and GND, where do these thresholds get generated? Am I correct in assuming that differential signals must be inverted, or would a +5V signal being complemented by a 0V signal (and leaving a +2.5V common mode voltage between them) be a viable signaling method in a system?

Differential signaling does not mean negative voltages. It simply means the signal is the difference of two wires.
Negative voltages are not required.
So a RS-422 transceiver does not need negative voltages for any purpose.
A simple comparator can also compare which wire has higher voltage than other wire without negative voltage.
So if one wire goes from 0V to 5V, the pair can go from 5V to 0V.
Voltage difference wires A-B can thus be 5V or -5V, depending on which is 0V and which is 5V.
That's perfectly differential, with common mode voltage of 2.5V.
